# How does Entity Framework track object with identity as key

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, identity

I want to understand how EF track ID when the primary key is identity. (DB first)

For example

```
class User
{
    int Id; //auto generated via SQL identity, also the primary key of the table Users.
    string Name;
}


//adding a new user-
User user = new User () {Name="TestUser"};//Id will be 0;
DB.Users.Add(user);
DB.SaveChanges();
user.Id; //Will have value;
```

More over if I have navigation property with foreign key to the user.Id will be updated as well.

I believe that EF track tables with the primary key, but in this case it is determined by SQL (or w/e) on creation, so how does the EF gets the actual ID after creation?

Answer (score 2):

I dont know EF, but Hibernate and Doctrine. I assume they are very similar.

EF keeps a reference to the object.

When `Add(Object)` is called, EF keeps a reference to the object in any case (it is needed to detect changes).

When `SaveChanges()`, is called, EF goes through all the references it has stored. It sees the `User` instance and knows that the PK strategy is IDENTITY and that the very instance has no PK value yet; As a result, EF decides to execute an `INSERT` statement for that instance. It then uses the DB driver to determine the ID of the row it just wrote and writes that value to the property. (Probably with `LAST_INSERT_ID()`).

Some pseudo code:

```
void Add(obj) {
    // add the object to the interal set of entities; this will keep track
    this.entitySet.add(obj);
}

void SaveChanges() {
    foreach entity in this.entitySet {
        if (isIdentityPK(entity) && !hasPKValue(entity)) {
            executeSQL("INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...)");
            id = executeSQL("LAST_INSERT_ID()");
            setEntityPKValue(entity, id);
        }
    }
}
```